# how pass value between fragments of same activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

Am new for android development issue am facing is i cannot pass the string value between fragments  of the same   activity
now let me briefly explain my requirements i have two fragments fragment b and fragment c .  whenever user select the value from the spinner in fragment c i should passed to the listview in fragment c so far i have tried is :

This is my Fragment New Requirement fragment(Fragment c):

```
package com.example.first.servicefirst;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class NewRequirements extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_claim, container,
                false);
        final Button btnupdate;
        btnupdate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.update);
        final Spinner sbu = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.sbuu);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptersbu = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.newrequirements, R.layout.spinnerlayout);
        adaptersbu.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sbu.setAdapter(adaptersbu);
        final Spinner bu = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.bu);

        adapterbu.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        bu.setAdapter(adapterbu);
        final Spinner sbuu = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.sbu);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptersbuu = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( 
        getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.newrequirements, R.layout.spinnerlayout);
        adaptersbuu.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sbuu.setAdapter(adaptersbuu);
        final Spinner sc = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.sc);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptersc = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.newrequirements, R.layout.spinnerlayout);
        adaptersc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sc.setAdapter(adaptersc);
        final Spinner ssc = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.ssc);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterssc = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                (getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.newrequirements, R.layout.spinnerlayout);
        adapterssc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ssc.setAdapter(adapterssc);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        final String str = sbu.getSelectedItem().toString();

        btnupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
                    Add add = new Add();

                    bundle.putString("yes", str);
                    Log.i("Bundle", bundle.toString());
                    Log.v("Add", str);
                    add.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, add,"hi");
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();


                }catch (Exception e){
                throw e;}
            }
        });
        return view;
    }catch (Exception e){
    throw e;
    }
 }

 }
```

This is Fragment Add (Fragment B)

```
  package com.example.first.servicefirst;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public  class Add extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
public static Add()
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_btn_add, container, false);
    Spinner ldsource=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lead_source);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.dropbox1, R.layout.spinnerlayout);


    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ldsource.setAdapter(adapter);
 //   EditText editText=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    Spinner ldtype=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ldtype);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.dropbox2,R.layout.spinnerlayout);

    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ldtype.setAdapter(adapter1);
    Spinner ldstatus=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ldstatus);
    TextView txt=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTarget);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.dropbox3, R.layout.spinnerlayout);

    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);
    ldstatus.setAdapter(adapter2);
  //  Bundle bundle=getArguments();
  //  String good=bundle.getString("sbu");
    ArrayList<LdNewsItem> listContact = GetlistContact();
    final   ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ldrequirements);
    lv.setAdapter(new customListAdapterldrequirements(getActivity(), listContact));
//    lv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  //      @Override
    //    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //        return false;
       // }

        // Setting on Touch Listener for handling the touch inside ScrollView


    //});
sbu = getArguments().getString("yes");
     return rootView;


}
```

Am getting null pointer exception at:   sbu = getArguments().getString("yes"); really Donno where am committing mistake it would be very helpful if some helps me Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure that **str** is not null at **bundle.putString("yes", str)**.

Comment: log displaying the selected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be with an `Interface` and handling all of the Fragment changing logic inside your `Activity`. I have quickly wrote up some code to show you how this would work. I have not included any constructors or `Fragment` instantiating and filling code. You will have to keep a reference to both of your `Fragment`'s inside your `Activity` and handle your `FragmentTransaction`'s in there.

Please let me know if you don't know how to do something and I'll try and add that to the example code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FragmentOneListener {

    private FragmentOne fragmentOne;
    private FragmentTwo fragmentTwo;


    @Override
    public void sendDataBack(String data) {
        if  (fragmentTwo != null) {
            fragmentTwo.doSomethingWithData(data);
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentOne.java**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    private FragmentOneListener fragmentOneListener;

    private void sendDataBack(String data) {
        if  (fragmentOneListener != null) {
            fragmentOneListener.sendDataBack(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
          fragmentOneListener = (FragmentOneListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()+ " must implement FragmentOneListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        fragmentOneListener = null;
    }

    public interface FragmentOneListener {
        void sendDataBack(String data);
    }
}
```

**FragmentTwo.java**

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    public void doSomethingWithData(String data) {

    }
}
```

Comment: why do we need on detach

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data between Fragment  you ca use following method.

1.You can use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) using this you can send data to LBM and you can implement the receiver on destination fragment which listen the broadcasted data.

2. You can implement callback listener between source and destination fragment.
   Using callback listener Source fragment will pass the data in callback method and destination fragment will listen it.Find Description [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)
3. Simple way you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) a third party library to pass data between two fragment.

Comment: thanks for the quick response @Avi cant we able to pass string between fragments of same activity by using bundle

Comment: Proper way are define above and if you want to use hack then their is no limitation in Android.